# How can i solve error 'The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'possID' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32'

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, file

I am trying to download a file on a Kendo Grid button click and now I am getting following error. I think that's the reason why I can't download the file.

My parameter returns an Id of the selected row which is `possId` but it throws this error:

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'possID' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.FileResult DownloadIndex(Int32)' in 'TTAF.Portal.Parts.Web.Controllers.PossController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter

**Download Action**

```
public FileResult DownloadIndex(int possID)
    {
        try
        {
            OnePossModel md = new Models.OnePossModel();
            JsonParamBuilder myBuilder = new JsonParamBuilder();
            myBuilder.AddParam<Guid>("submittingUserID", System.Guid.Parse(User.Identity.GetUserId()));
            myBuilder.AddParam<int>("possID", Convert.ToInt32(possID));

            string jsonReq = Models.JsonWrapper.JsonPOST(ApiBaseUrl + ApiPOSSSubBaseUrl + "/WritePOSSFile", myBuilder.GetJSonParam());
            string possFilename = Models.DeserialiseFromJson<string>.DeserialiseApiResponse(jsonReq);

            possFilename = possFilename.Replace(",", ",");
            var type = System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet;

            byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(Filelocation + possFilename );
            Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + possFilename);
            return File(fileBytes, type, possFilename);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
```

**Javasrcipt**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
                       function showDetails(e) {
                           e.preventDefault();
                           var dataItem = this.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr"));
                           DownloadIndexController(dataItem.possID);
                       }
                </script>


            <script>
                    function DownloadIndexController(possID) {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: '@Url.Action("DownloadIndex", "Poss")',
                            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                            datatype: 'json',
                            data: { possID: possID },
                            type: "GET",
                            success: function (data) {
                                window.location = '@Url.Action("DownloadIndex", "Poss")';
                            }
                        })
                    }
            </script>
```

**my view**

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("SearchPoss", "Poss", Model.possID, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Post" }, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form"}))
{

   @(Html.Kendo().Grid<Web.Models.OnePossModel.GridPossModels>()
            .Name("Grid")
                  .Columns(columns =>
                  {
                      columns.Command(command => command.Custom("Download").Click("showDetails")).Width(100);
                      columns.Bound(x => x.possID).Title("ID");
                      columns.Bound(x => x.ordernumber).Title("Order Number");
                      columns.Bound(x => x.datePublishedBySap).Title("Poss Date").Format("{0:" + System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern + "}");
                      columns.Bound(x => x.possType).Title("Poss Type");
                      columns.Bound(x => x.possSource).Title("Poss Source");

                  })
                  .Pageable(pageable => pageable
                    .Refresh(true)
                    .PageSizes(true)
                    .ButtonCount(5))
                  .Scrollable()
                  .Filterable()
                  .Sortable()
                  .Resizable(resize => resize.Columns(true))
                  .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                  .Ajax()
                  .PageSize(10)
                  .ServerOperation(false) //No post back
                  .Read(read => read.Action("ReadPoss", "Poss"))))

}
```

Comment: Make sure using e.g. `alert(dataItem.possID);` that the item really produces a valid ID. Also worth a try is to use **[Telerik Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler)** to see what data is being sent from your browser to the server.

Comment: why don't you test if dataItem.possID exist and if not do a return?

Comment: @PeterB i have already alert it and am getting the same id which is being passed to the controller

Comment: @federicoscamuzzi can you please show me what you mean, bit lost. thanks

Answer (score 0):

This problem is self explanatory that `DownloadIndex(int possID)` need of int type of parameter but somehow the parameter value is null. When you are issuing request to this action method from your ajax call. Parameter  **data: { possID: possID },** is passing null value in action method. The problem could be in this piece of code

```
 function showDetails(e) {
                           e.preventDefault();
                           var dataItem = this.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr"));
                           DownloadIndexController(dataItem.possID);
                       }
```

where dataItem.possID is not supplying any value. Try to ensure in developer tool that dataItem.possId has value. If you are sure that it could pass null value to controller action method then please give default value in action method to avoid this kind of exception like

```
public FileResult DownloadIndex(int possID = 10OrAnyDegaultNumber) //default value for your possID.
```

Comment: I have alerted the dataitem and i got the same id which is being passed to the controller as well. my question is, when i give it default value,how will it know which file to download because the user can just select any row from the grid and click download button

Comment: I suggested  you to avoid exception suppose if no value is passed then put id =xxxx and match in if condition if id == xxx then simple show some value in grid "No content is downloaded"  because it could be possible some script could not be downloaded in those cases you will again suffer with this kind of problem.

Comment: Can you please show me from the code i have posted so that i will know the direction

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just check the value of the dataItem.possID and if it empty or not the rigth for you you exit... something like:

```
 function showDetails(e) {
                               e.preventDefault();
                               var dataItem = this.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr"));
if(!dataItem || !dataItem.possID) return; //and maybe other check you want
                               DownloadIndexController(dataItem.possID);
                           }
```

Comment: I am still getting the same error even thou i have done the checks